# How to unite two different columns into one column in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe named `sales_raw` with 28 columns and 2823 rows. It has two address columns, `Address_1` and `Address_2`. `Address_2` is detail address of `Address_1`. I want to unite them without any conditional and keep the new column `Address` in the same dataframe.

How to do this? Is there any alternative to do this?

Note: I have some NaN values in the column `Address_2`

Comment: I tried to code like this ```sales_raw['Address'] = sales_raw['Adress_1'] + sales_raw['Address_2']``` but Python returned NaN values from Address_2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.where`:

```
>>> sales_raw
  Address_1 Address_2
0  AddressA   DetailA
1  AddressB       NaN
2  AddressC   DetailC
```

```
sales_raw['Address'] = np.where(sales_raw['Address_2'].isna(),
                                sales_raw['Address_1'],
                                sales_raw['Address_1'] + ', ' + sales_raw['Address_2'])
```

```
>>> sales_raw
  Address_1 Address_2            Address
0  AddressA   DetailA  AddressA, DetailA
1  AddressB       NaN           AddressB
2  AddressC   DetailC  AddressC, DetailC
```

Comment: @JosephArmandoCarvallo, I added the comma as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```py
df["Address"] = df["Address_1"] + df["Address_2"].fillna("")
```

This will concatenate the values of the two columns while using missing values from the second column with empty strings.

Comment: How to add comma to the union (Address)?

Answer (score 1):

Since `str` concatenations are also vectorized, you can simply do:

```
df["Address"] = df.pop("Address_1") + " " + df.pop("Address_2")
```

You can use `df.insert()` if you'd like to insert the new column at a specific position.